# ReplayKit tvOS issue

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, avassetwriter, replaykit

I am using ReplayKit to record screen on tvOS and pushing CMBufferSample to RTMP server as received. However as shown in the attachment, for some reason it looks like it is redrawing over the existing content. I tried saving it locally in a file as well using AVAssetWriter but same issue.[image]

Things work fine on iOS and macOS but cause this issue on tvOS.